# How create message box in Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, autohotkey, messagebox

I am newbie in Puppeteer and i am trying to rewrite my Autohotkey scripts. I cannot find yet how create message box in Puppeteer as in Autohotkey. Is it even possible?
Something like this:

```
Sleep, 300
MsgBox, Its finded!
WinActivate ahk_exe firefox.exe
WinMaximize ahk_exe firefox.exe
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what is Message box?

Comment: https://ibb.co/pPhR9qb

Answer (score 0):

`puppeteer` is a node.js package that uses a headless (invisible) Chromium browser, so by itself it is unable to show a dialog box as that browser has no GUI.

However using another package like [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier) in your script you can send a system notification:

[image]

And to run a program at the end of your script you would use a package like [execa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa).

Comment: Thank you, i will try this node-notifier.